# How to query kernel memory pool status without triggering OOM killer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system, ram

I know that kernel will emit detailed system memory status to kernel log when OOM Killer is triggered. Is there a way to query this information while the system is running normally?

I know that basic info can be found at `/proc/meminfo` but the details I cannot find is following lines in the OOM Killer output (example from my system):

```
Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15888k
B
Node 0 DMA32: 14121*4kB (UME) 18163*8kB (UME) 12588*16kB (UME) 5074*32kB (UME) 1404*64kB (UME) 484*128kB (UME) 19*256kB (UME) 0*512k
B 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 722236kB
Node 0 Normal: 399161*4kB (UME) 126769*8kB (UME) 74232*16kB (UME) 26738*32kB (UME) 5767*64kB (UME) 1079*128kB (UME) 50*256kB (UE) 2*
512kB (U) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 5175148kB
```

This information tells how much free RAM the system has ready for future memory requests. I'm trying to minimize system latency and I'd like to collect and log information about how much free space I normally have in each bucket so I could better understand abnormal situation when the OOM Killer is activated because the system is often seeing high latency before that.

Is the information in the above three lines available accessible using vanilla Linux kernel without triggering OOM Killer? (Obviously, NUMA systems could have more RAM nodes so the above lines are the minimum info.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct file is called `/proc/buddyinfo` and it looks like this:

```
$ cat /proc/buddyinfo 
Node 0, zone      DMA      0      0      1      0      2      1      1      0      1      1      3 
Node 0, zone    DMA32  52816  22757  16135   7177   2517    548     19      0      0      0      0 
Node 0, zone   Normal  27530 148696  45276   3778   6814   3711    222      0      0      0      0
```

The line with "zone DMA32" will be missing if the kernel is running with 32 bit kernel. See http://andorian.blogspot.com/2014/03/making-sense-of-procbuddyinfo.html for details.

The the reason why this matters is that you may end up triggering kernel OOM Killer because of memory fragmentation in case the requested memory size is bigger than the biggest available contiguous memory area. The details about memory fragmentation can be found here: http://events17.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/%5BELC-2015%5D-System-wide-Memory-Defragmenter.pdf